# libgdx DragListener cancellation

Tags: libgdx, drag-and-drop

Trying to use libgdx's drag listener, I realized that the #cancel method would only be called AFTER #dragStop even if ESC is pressed before the mouse button release, which is practically preventing me from cancelling the action meanwhile.
So how am I supposed to deal with my selection cancellation? With an additional keyboard input listener, perhaps?
So what is the functional point with the cancel method?

Thanks for any lights here.

Answer (score 0):

For now, I'll just be checking up Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.ESCAPE) at render time, not using #cancel anymore.